# What does this if-statement exactly do?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm developing a `Discord Bot` using `discord.js` V12 and there are some lines in my code that I just don't understand.

#### My command handler:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
    for(const file of command_files) {
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        
     //This is the if statement I dont understand   
      if(command.name)
        {
        client.commands.set(command.name, command); // and also this line thx.
        } else
        {
            continue;
        }
   }
};
```

Can someone explain these to me? Thanks.

Comment: @Toasty thanks it helped and thank you for making my question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `if statement`

```js
if(command.name)
```

checks, whether the property `name` of `commands` is **empty or not**.

- If it's empty, it will **not execute the code inside the brackets and jump straight to the `else block`
- If not, it will execute the code inside the brackets

The second line

```js
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

calls the [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) function to add a new command with these parameters to the `commands` collection:

- `command.name` obviously the name of the `command` to be added
- the `command` obeject itself with all properties and executable functions